# Algorithms to check Pattern Avoidance Permutations

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, algorithms

My question is the following: Given two permutations $\pi \in S_{n}$ and $\mu \in S_{k}$, decide whether $\pi$ is $\mu$-avoiding or not.

I think the formal definition is quite hard to write in the most general fashion. Therefore, I will give the definition for the case $\mu = 132$, hopefully it will be clear for a general $\mu$ as well.

*Side Note:* I am writing permutations as words, i.e $\mu = 132$ means that $\mu$ is the permutation that maps $1$ to $1$, $2$ to $3$ and $3$ to $2$.

**Definition:** A permutation $\pi \in S_n$ is called $132$-avoiding if there does not exist integers $a_1 < a_2 < a_3$ such that $\pi(a_1) < \pi(a_3) < \pi(a_2)$. In other words, no subsequence of $\pi$ of length $3$ has its terms in the same relative order as 132.

*Examples:*

1- Let $\pi = 42153$. Then, $\pi$ is not $132$-avoiding since the subsequence $153$ of $\pi$ has the same relative order of $132$(i.e the smallest element is at the left hand, the largest element is the middle element and the middle element is at  the right hand.)

2- Let $\pi = 1573246$. Then, $\pi$ is not $1432$-avoiding since the subsequence $1732$ of $\pi$ has the same relative order of $1432$. However, $pi$ is $12345$-avoiding since $\pi$ has no length $5$ increasing subsequence.

Thus, the question becomes the following: Given $\pi \in S_n$ and $\mu \in S_k$, find an efficient algorithm to check whether $\pi$ is $\mu$-avoiding or not.

Obviously, one can check all $\binom{n}{k}$ subsequences of length $k$ of $\pi$ to check whether $\pi$ is $\mu$-avoiding or not. However, it is not efficient.

*Side Note2:* I can only come up with some simple constraints to conclude that $\pi$ is **not** $\mu$-avoiding such as:

1- $k$ > $n$, or

2- The number of inversions of $\mu$ is larger than $\pi$.

Thanks in advance for suggestions or(and) help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is NP complete, so no efficient algorithm (likely) exists. For a proof, see

> Bose, Prosenjit, Buss, J.F., and Lubiw, A. “Pattern Matching for Permutations”. Information Processing Letters 65.5 (1998): 277–283.

You might be able to get the paper [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020019097002093) if your institution gives you access.